# using line breaks in meta tags

Tags: php, html, meta-tags, line-breaks

I want to use line breaks in my website description meta tag. How do I do it, because if I see the source code it will still show `<br/>` only. Something like this I use in my code:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $gotAlias ?><br/>
abc: <?php echo $got_overallrating ?>.<br/>
<a href='www.abc.com'>Visit www.abc.com</a>
">
```

Comment: I am curious to know the reason behind why the line breaks are needed.

Comment: like i share my page to FB and all ...so i need my description to be clear there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `"\n"` instead of `<br />`, e.g. `<?php echo "first line\nsecond line"; ?>`;

Answer (score 4):

For use in AddThis meta content tagging, the \n is ignored.
So it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
//META TAGS
add_action( 'wp_head', 'tws_output_meta_tags', 5 );
function tws_output_meta_tags() {
    echo '<meta name="author" content="content text" />'."\n";   

}
```