# Is it allowed to have line breaks in HTML5 meta's content?

Tags: html

Given one meta tag as an example:

`<meta property="og:description" content="this is just a content">`

Is it allowed to have line breaks in that meta's content field?

The reason to ask this is because I like to fill description in Open Graph programmably, which is to extract summary from full content. There would be some line breaks in the extract summary and I'm wondering if it is allowable here.

Comment: Why would you put a new line in there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using line breaks in meta tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694400/using-line-breaks-in-meta-tags)

Comment: Another possible duplicate [Facebook send dialog: adding a linebreak in the description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348980/facebook-send-dialog-adding-a-linebreak-in-the-description)

Comment: @Kaiido: This is about newlines within a single attribute value, not newlines between multiple different attributes.

Comment: @BoltClock you are absolutely right, didn't noticed the "*in that meta's **content** field?*" in OP.

Comment: Balint: One use case, perhaps: in Android, when txt'ing a website to someone, a card is generated. Here, the subtitle of my website gets cut-off because it doesn't wrap. Naturally I would want to try to put a line break there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the idea seems horribly awful to me, I've not found anything in the HTML5 specification that forbids it

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-content

Specifically, for the description property, the specification states:
"The value must be a free-form string that describes the page. The value must be appropriate for use in a directory of pages, e.g. in a search engine. There must not be more than one meta element with its name attribute set to the value description per document"

Wich makes me believe that you can insert even HTML inside the content attribute.