# How to make lines in og:description in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a description in my website and I want to make new lines in it. Can I do this? If then please help me

My code

```
<meta property="og:description" content="This is 1st line. This should be 2nd. And this should be 3rd line"/>
```

I want the content result to be like

```
This is 1st line.
This should be 2nd.
And this should be 3rd line
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

character entities work in attributes, so this might work:"&#10";

like that:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="&#10;This is 1st line.&#10;This should be 2nd.&#10; And this should be 3rd line"/>
```

```
<meta property="og:description" content="
This is 1st line.
This should be 2nd.
And this should be 3rd line">
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually try it, but why not just add "\n".

```
<meta property="og:description" content="This is 1st line.\n This should be 2nd.\n And this should be 3rd line"/>
```

[using line breaks in meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694400/using-line-breaks-in-meta-tags)

Comment: This method doesn't work in content